# Javascript: Can't pass variables as parameters with onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, arguments

I have this code (jquery):

```
function somefunction() {

        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        dataType : 'json',

        success : function(data){

            var mess = "";  
            var count = 0;

            while (count < (data.length - 1))
            {

                 mess = mess + "<a href=# onclick=deletePerson("JohnDoe");return false;><img src=x.gif></a>" + data[count].name + "<br />";
                 count++;
            }


            $('#mydiv').html(mess).fadeIn('fast');


        },
    });


}
function deletePerson(arg) {...}
```

When I run this, everything works fine.
However, when I want to pass a variable (instead of "JohnDoe") with the onclick, it stops working:

```
var myvar = "JohnDoe";
mess = mess + "<a href=# onclick=delete(myvar);return false;><img src=x.gif></a>" + data[count].name + "<br />";
```

My editor tells me: "Unresolved variable or type".

Never had a problem with passing parameters, but with this onClick-thing it just doesn't work...

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thank's a lot!

EDIT: Joseph's post fixed the JohnDoe problem (thanks!), however, when I put:

```
var myvar = data[count].name;
```

it stops working... any thoughts?

Comment: can you tell what's coming with data variable ?

Comment: Creating HTML and binding event handlers like this is error prone and therefore bad style. Consider using jQuery to do this.

Comment: this is a very bad way to bind events. If you're using jquery, you should *use* it: `$('<a href="#">').click(...)...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the variable in

```
myvar = "JohnDoe";
mess = mess + "<a href=# onclick=delete('"+myvar+"');return false;><img src=x.gif></a>" + data[count].name + "<br />";
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around the argument.

Comment: Also maybe take the var off of "var myvar" so it becomes global, don't know where he/she is declaring it.

Comment: Ok, now it works with "JohnDoe". However, I need the var to be data[count].name. So when I put `var myvar = data[count].name;` (inside the while loop off course) it stops working again... The delete() function doesn't get called, nothing happens. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`delete` is a reserved keyword in javascript, you should rename your function.

```
...
mess = mess + "<a href=# onclick=deletePerson('"+myvar+"');return false;><img src=x.gif></a>" + data[count].name + "<br />";
...
function deletePerson(name) {...}
```

Comment: My bad, the function isn't actually named delete, but the translation of "to delete" in my native language. Changed it for stackoverflow, but hadn't thought about the reserved-keyword-thing. Thanks for pointing this out, problem still unfixed though...

Comment: @binoculars Are you sure data is an array? Do a console.log() to check it out, maybe it's a string, or maybe the array elements don't have a `name` property. Also, you should update the code in your post so that it matches the current state.

Comment: I'm sure it's an array and it exists, since the while loop with `data[count].name` inside it works just fine... (update my code)